# C++ overloading template on assigning value or callback function

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

Trying to do something like...

```
template <class T>
struct Wrapper
{
    template <class U>
    void set(const U& u) { myT = u; }

    template <class F>
    void set(F f) { myT = f(); }

    T myT;
};
```

I know I need to use SFINAE here but how do I distinguish a callback parameter from a value parameter? It's safe to assume that a value can't be used as a callback.

I've tried `enable_if` with `is_function, result_of`, `invoke_result`, `is_invocable`, and others, but none of it works right. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it without SFINAE:

```
template<class U>
void set(const U& u) { 
    if constexpr (std::is_invocable_v<U>)
        myT = u();
    else
        myT = u;
}
```

or in a more generic way:

```
template<class U>
void set(U&& u) { 
    if constexpr (std::is_invocable_v<U>)
        myT = std::forward<U>(u)();
    else
        myT = std::forward<U>(u);
}
```

Comment: prefer `constexpr` over SFINAE because of better compile times

Answer (score 7):

Yes you can apply SFINAE with the help of [`std::is_invocable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_invocable) (since C++17).

```
template <class U>
std::enable_if_t<!std::is_invocable_v<U>> set(const U& u) { myT = u; }

template <class F>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_invocable_v<F>> set(F f) { myT = f(); }
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/tWV7aHhUKr9WhOia)

Answer (score 4):

The overload that takes a function as an argument can be defined as:

```
template <typename R>
   void set(R (*f)())
   {
      myT = f();
   }
```

Demonstrative code:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
struct Wrapper
{
   template <class U>
      void set(const U& u)
      {
         std::cout << "In set(const U& u)\n";
         myT = u;
      }

   template <typename R>
      void set(R (*f)())
      {
         std::cout << "In set(R (*f)())\n";
         myT = f();
      }

   T myT;
};

short foo()
{
   return 2u;
}

int main()
{
   Wrapper<int> a;
   a.set(1u);
   a.set(foo);
}
```

Output:

```
In set(const U& u)
In set(R (*f)())
```

Comment: This is a poor solution. Your are accepting only function pointers. You cannot pass lambdas nor "callable classes".